# Is there a way to restrict the operation of a driver or even record the action of the driver in Blender

Tags: animation, keyframes, drivers, fcurves

I have a small animation playing and I have made use of some trajectory equations in order to obtain a more realistic jump in the form of a driver, but I also want to add some additional movements to the object, is there a way to record the action  of the driver to form an f-curve and then delete the driver?

Answer (score 1):

In pose mode go to Menu: Pose-Animation-Bake action. Check the visual keying option. Then you can use the newly created action on a copy of the armature without any costraint or driver.